# Visual Studio 2010 extension to add extension methods to intellisense even if the using statement isn't there

Tags: visual-studio-2010, extension-methods, visual-studio-extensions

I've gotten used to adding `using System.Linq;` for `IEnumerable` extension methods, but there have been times when I've tried to use an extension method on a class and it didn't show up in intellisense and I spent way too much time trying to figure out what's wrong before realizing I just need a using statement that Visual Studio didn't find for me. Is there a VS2010 extension that will find extension methods in the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> `View.ShowSmartTag` feature?

Comment: You want VS to search _every_ `static` class in every assembly you've referenced for extension methods? That would be slow.

Comment: isn't VS scanning every assembly anyways?

Comment: Yes, but not every static class.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just type the name of the extension method class, then do a `Ctrl + .` on it. I just tested that and it should work even if the namespace is different. Or are you wondering if there is a way to just type variable.Ext() and do `ctrl + .` period on that? Although I tested on VS 2012 so maybe that's why. I am not aware of any extension to automatically detect extension methods.

Comment: 4 years old. I should be ashamed of myself.